# private class outside namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces

I want to create a class outside a namespace so that its default access modifier is 'PRIVATE'. I am doing like this:

```
namespace KnowStructs
{
    class Clas1 {}
}

class MyClass {}
```

But still my class **'MyClass'** is referred as Internal when I look in Reflector.
Can anyone help me out.

Comment: Ok I have got the answer.

When I declare a nested class it is PRIVATE by default.
But still can anyone tell how to define a class outside a namespace so that its default namespace is private

Comment: Please rephrase you question, if no access modifier is provided for the class, it is 'private', and so is true for your code snippet as well. And internal means you class cant be accessed outside the assembly.

Comment: what do you mean by 'private namespace'?

Comment: Hi Abdul,Please paste my code an just see the dll created in Reflector. Its actually internal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a private class is allowed that is not a nested type then what would that mean? If it is more restrictive than `internal` then how would you use it or create an instance. Any use case will require it to be `internal` at a minimum. I would like to see how you intend to use it.

It simply makes no logical sense.

Whereas having a private nested class scopes itself to the parent containing class. If it were `internal` then you still will be able to make an instance within the assembly.

So for classes having no modifier is `internal` by default for non nested types and `private` for nested types as .Net always applies the most restrictive access when no modifier is specified.

Answer (score 2):

From [Accessibility Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> Top-level types, which are not nested in other types, can only have internal or public accessibility. The default accessibility for these types is internal.

and:

> Access modifiers are not allowed on namespaces. Namespaces have no access restrictions.

and for [private](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx):

> Private members are accessible only within the body of the class or the struct in which they are declared

That is, the private keyword is explicitly defined in terms of a containing class or struct.

So whatever you're trying to do, I don't understand it. How could a top level private type possibly be useful? No other code would be able to reference it (in any way, even if it had e.g. static factory methods).

Answer (score 0):

You can make the class `internal`, if you only want to be accessible by classes in your namespace

Comment: Actually this will make it accessible by the whole assembly, not just the single namespace. Also, the OP wants to make it `private`.